# json module behaving differently in Python3 [python3]

Tags: json, python-2.7, serialization, python-3.5

I have been tasked with migrating our flask app from Python2.7 to Python3.5 and so far I thought I had much of the differences between the two versions covered. However, as I was testing the app, I ran into a problem with how JSONs are being de/serialized in python3 that took quite a bit of my time. So our app is run on gunicorn on nginx. The box it is running on is an AWS EC2 with Ubuntu 16.04 OS image.

So I am testing our app by doing several POST requests to one of our endpoints (this is done via the POSTMAN extension on Chrome). In our code, we de-serialize the POST'ed json like this:

```
import json
data = json.loads(payload)  # where payload is the POST'ed json and we get payload from flask.request.data
```

OK cool, this works in python2.7 and lets says data looks like:

```
{"hello": "world"}
```

However, in python3.5, for some freakin' reason, payload's data-type is now bytes and my understanding about everything breaks down (this is only only for `json.loads` btw)

```
data = json.loads(payload)  # TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'
data = json.loads(str(payload))  # json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
data = json.loads(str(payload, "utf-8")) # ok, this one works but why?
```

Ok, so now I got the JSON loads to finally work, but now I have to perform a `json.dumps` elsewhere in the code. Lets say I have a dictionary `data`.

```
data = {"hello": "world", "stuff": [{"foo": 1}, {"bar": 2}]}
```

In python2.7, this is fine but in python3.5:

```
return json.dumps(data)  # TypeError: 214 is not JSON serializable
return json.dumps(str(data)) # This works? WTF
```

Does all this have something to do with Python3.5 assuming all strings to be unicode now? 
Thanks for taking the time to read this